# Why auto_prepend_file take no effect in php's interactive mode?

Tags: php, load, interactive

Install package via composer and import it :

```
mkdir  myproject
cd myproject
composer require metowolf/meting
mkdir public
touch public/index.php
```

Load it in the index.php:

```
cd public
vim  index.php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
use Metowolf\Meting;
$api = new Meting('netease');
```

Display the project directory structure:

```
tree myproject
myproject
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── public
│   └── index.php
└── vendor
    ├── autoload.php
    ├── composer
    │   ├── autoload_classmap.php
    │   ├── autoload_namespaces.php
    │   ├── autoload_psr4.php
    │   ├── autoload_real.php
    │   ├── autoload_static.php
    │   ├── ClassLoader.php
    │   ├── installed.json
    │   └── LICENSE
    └── metowolf
        └── meting
            ├── composer.json
            ├── LICENSE
            ├── README.md
            └── src
                └── Meting.php
```

Verify it in browser  `127.0.0.1/myproject/public`,it works fine,the package `Megting` was loaded.

Now ,i want to load it in interactive mode:

```
php  -d auto_prepend_file=/home/debian/myproject/vendor/metowolf/meting/src/Meting.php  -a
Interactive mode enabled
php > use Metowolf\Meting;
php > $api = new Meting('netease');
PHP Warning:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Meting' not found in php shell code:1
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in php shell code on line 1
```

Why auto_prepend_file take no effect in php's interactive mode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`auto_prepend_file` does work in interactive shell. The issue is that the `use` keyword has an effect only on the current line.

With this prepend.php file:

```php
<?php
namespace foo;

class Bar
{
    function __construct()
    {
        echo 'Success';
    }
}
?>
```

This works (full class name):

```
php -d auto_prepend_file=prepend.php -a
Interactive shell

php > new foo\Bar();
Success
```

This also works (`use` and `new` on the same line):

```
php -d auto_prepend_file=prepend.php -a
Interactive shell

php > use foo\Bar; new Bar();
Success
```

This fails:

```
php -d auto_prepend_file=prepend.php -a
Interactive shell

php > use foo\Bar;
php > new Bar();
PHP Warning:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Bar' not found in php shell code:1
```